# Font awesome icons wont show up. Only in localhost

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am hosting on awardspace and am trying to show font awesome icons. While developing in localhost everything worked fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://spaiosos.de/library/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="#contact" class="page-scroll" id="contacts"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></a>
```

I also tried with only `library/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` still not working though. Also strange was that my .png images weren't showing up so I just uploaded them separately in awardspace and they showed up. Tried the same with the fa folders but it's not working.

Comment: cannot access the domain `spaiosos.de` .. try other cdns like cdnjs or pull the file on you project and host it on your own server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried opening the link in the `href` but no page can be found
try using different CDN like https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome

Comment: thanks its working but still cant figure out why it should work only local.

Comment: I guess this is related to configuration of the hosted site

Answer (score 0):

Working example using social media icons:

```
<!-- FontAwesome Icons (Start) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
    .fa {
        color: #666 !important;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    .fa:hover {
        color: #000 !important;
    }

    .social_icons a:nth-child(1) i {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
<div class="social_icons">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
<!-- FontAwesome Icons (End) -->
```